# jQuery Validate plugin problems

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm not all that familiar with the Jquery validator plugin, and I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to validate a single text field, i.e. entering a password into a text field and if it's equal to 'password' (or whatever the password may be) then the download link appears.

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aSRRr/

Here's the jQuery too:

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
submitHandler: function(form){
$("#myform").hide();
$("#download-file").fadeIn("slow");
},
}); 


  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    password: { required: true, equalTo: "#password"},
  }

});

  });


$(document).ready(function(){
$("#myform").hide();
$("#download-file").hide();

$("#download-button").click(function(){
$("#myform").fadeToggle(300);
});
});
```

Is it possible to validate a text field against a word, in this case 'password'?

Comment: The `equalTo` rule is only meant for comparing the value of two different input fields to each other.

Comment: Please be aware that storing a password in JavaScript is not secure.  Anyone can see the password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**IMPORTANT NOTE:  This is not secure.**  Anyone could easily view any of your JavaScript code and look at the value of your password.

The following answers your question, although I don't recommend this as a reliable way to secure anything.

---

Use [the jQuery Validate plugin's built-in `addMethod` method](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod#namemethodmessage) to create a custom rule called `pw_check` as follows:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("pw_check", function (value) {
    return (value == 'password');
}, "Invalid password");
```

Then apply the new rule along with your other rules...

```
rules: {
    password: {
        required: true,
        pw_check: true // <-- apply your custom rule
    }
},
```

**The fully updated jQuery code:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    jQuery.validator.addMethod("pw_check", function (value) {
        return (value == 'password');
    }, "Invalid password");

    $("#myform").validate({
        rules: {
            password: {
                required: true,
                pw_check: true
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            $("#myform").hide();
            $("#download-file").fadeIn("slow");
        }
    });

    $("#myform").hide();
    $("#download-file").hide();

    $("#download-button").click(function () {
        $("#myform").fadeToggle(300);
    });

});
```

There are no changes to your HTML.

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/5WMNK/**

Answer (score 2):

Use the `addMethod` function http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod :

> Add a custom validation method. It must consist of a name (must be a
>   legal javascript identifier), a javascript based function and a
>   default string message. The arguments to the callback are:
>   - the current value of the validated element
>
> - the element to be validated
> - parameters specified for the method, e.g. for min: 5 the parameter is 5, for range: [1, 5] its [1, 5]
>
> Please note: While the temptation
>   is great to add a regex method that checks it's parameter against the
>   value, it is much cleaner to encapsulate those regular expressions
>   inside their own method. If you need lots of slightly different
>   expressions, try to extract a common parameter.

Markup:

```
<div id="download-button" style="cursor: pointer;">Download File</div>

<form id="myform">
  <label for="password">Password</label>
  <input id="password" name="password" class="isPassword" />
  <br/>

  <input class="submit" type="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
</form>

<div id="download-file" style="cursor: pointer;">Click to Download</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    submitHandler: function(form){
        $("#myform").hide();
        $("#download-file").fadeIn("slow");
    },
}); 
$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("isPassword", function(value) {
        if(value == 'password')
              return true;
          }, "Invalid password");
    $("#myform").validate();
    $("#myform").hide();
    $("#download-file").hide();
    $("#download-button").click(function(){
        $("#myform").fadeToggle(300);
    });
});
```

Make sure your input uses the class isPassword. Also make sure to remove the extra `.ready` function from your code.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aSRRr/2/